# org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TopicAuthorizationException: Not authorized to access topics:

Tags: java, spring-boot, ssl, apache-kafka, kafka-producer-api

Here is the code where I am trying to write to a kafka topic :

```
@Service
public class KafkaMessageSender {

@Autowired
KafkaTemplate<String, History> kafkaTemplate;

@Value(value = "${my.kafka.topic}")
private String topicName;

@Autowired
public KafkaMessageSender(KafkaTemplate<String, History> kafkaTemplate) {
    this.kafkaTemplate = kafkaTemplate;
}

public History writeToTopic(final History entry) throws Exception {

  
    try {
        String key = entry.getValue();
        SendResult<String,History> future = kafkaTemplate.send(topicName, key, entry).get();
        recordMetadata = future.getRecordMetadata();
        if (future.getRecordMetadata() != null) {
            LOGGER.info("message successfully sent to kafka);
        }

    } catch (KafkaException e) {
   
    }
    return entry;
}
```

My connection is not getting established to Kafka. Don't understand what is the issue.

Here is the stacktrace :

```
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.springframework.kafka.core.KafkaProducerException: Failed to send; nested exception is org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TopicAuthorizationException: Not authorized to access topics: [kaas.my_topic]
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122) ~[?:?]
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:191) ~[?:?]
at org.springframework.util.concurrent.SettableListenableFuture.get(SettableListenableFuture.java:119) ~[spring-core-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
at com.optum.chy.kafka.KafkaMessageSender.writeToTopic(KafkaMessageSender.java:42) ~[classes/:?]
```

Comment: Talk to your Kafka administrator about authorization policies